# Programmatically set identity seed in a table variable

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a table variable with an identity seed that starts with the max value of a field in another table?

I've tried this:

```
DECLARE @IdentitySeed int

SET @IdentitySeed = (SELECT MAX(HHRecId) +1 FROM xxx )

DECLARE @HH TABLE (
    HHId INT IDENTITY(@IdentitySeed,1)
    ,AddressType CHAR(1)
    ,Address1 VARCHAR(100)
    ,City VARCHAR(50)
    ,State VARCHAR(2)
    ,Zip VARCHAR(5)
    ,LastName VARCHAR(50)
    )
```

But that gives a syntax error.

For now, I've added another int column to the table variable and update that with the sum of the identity column and @IdentitySeed but I would like to find a way to do that without the update.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check the current value of an IDENTITY column by using:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (#HH)
```

and you can also change that later on using:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (#HH, RESEED, 42)
```

and that also works with a variable for the new value:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (#HH, RESEED, @IdentitySeed)
```

It works for local and global temporary tables (i.e.  `CREATE TABLE #HH (...)` or `CREATE TABLE ##HH (....)` - but it doesn't seem to work with table variables :-(

Sorry, it seems you can't do this with table variables.....

Answer (score 5):

I ended up doing the following:

```
DECLARE @NewId INT

SELECT @NewId = MAX(ID) FROM MyIDSTable

DECLARE @MyTempData TABLE (
    Id int not null primary key
    ,Field1 int not null
    ,Field2 nvarchar(25) not null
    ,Field3 datetime
)

INSERT INTO @MyTempData
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( Order by [C].[Cancel_id] ASC) + @NewId -1 [RowNum]
        ,Field1
        ,Field2
        ,Field3

INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM @MyTempData

UPDATE MYIDSTable SET ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @MyTempData) + 1 WHERE Name = 'Something'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do this, but it'll have to be done in dynamic SQL - declare the tableVar in the dynamic SQL and use it there too!

It would surely be easier and result in faster code if you started it at 1 and had a secondary ID field that is calculated as MAX(HHRecId) + ID.